# Can a $k$-regular graph with $99$ vertices $(G=(99,E))$ be a bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I was reviewing some exams from previous years on Graph Theory and I'm stuck on this question.

What I have so far is that for a graph to be bipartite, we need to have $2$ subsets of $V=99$

$(G=(V,E) \Rightarrow G=(X \cup Y, E))$, where:

$|V(X)|+|V(Y)|=|V(G)|=99$

$|V(X)|\cdot|V(Y)|=|E|$

$|E|=\dfrac{k|V(G)|}{2}$

Do I just solve these equations for k or am I completely off and need to prove this some other way?

Comment: Why is $|V(X)| * |V(Y)|=|E|$?

Comment: Oh my bad. Just realized it is not necessarily a complete bipartite graph. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that in a regular bipartite graph you have 
$$|E|=|V(X)|*k=|V(Y)|*k$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Basically since from every subset the number of edges is going to be the number of vertices of that subset times k (since the degree is the same in a regular graph) V(x)*k=V(y)*k thus V(x)=V(y). but for 99 vertices we cannot really divide them into two equal subsets thus this graph doesn't exist?

Comment: @TheAlexie It can exist if $k=0$.

Comment: @TheAlexie As pointed by bof $V(x) k=V(y)k \Rightarrow V(x)=V(y)$ requires $k \neq 0$. So, as long as $k \neq 0$ the argument works, but technically the Null graph $N_{99}$ is 0regular and bipartite.